# No hay respuesta en comandos AT via ESP32+SIM7600X 4G HAT

Tags: serialport

He conectado la placa **SIM7600X 4G HAT** a un **ESP32**.

Estoy usando la liberia ***Adafruit_FONA.h***

Estoy `HardwareSerial *fonaSerial = &Serial2;` ya que el **SerialSoftware** me da problemas, `fona.begin(*fonaSerial)` detecta correctamente la placa **SIM7600X 4G HAT**, pero al enviar *comandos AT* algo va mal.

Por ejemplo:

```
sendATcommand("AT+CREG?","OK",2000);
```

No hay respuesta.

Si muestro las lecturas dentro de la función `sendATcommand` de la siguiente manera:

```
  Serial.println(ATcommand);
  Serial.println(fonaSerial->available());
  Serial.println(fonaSerial->read());
```

Las respuestas són las siguientes:

> ```
> AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","NXT17C.NET"
> 0
> -1
> AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
> 0
> -1
> AT+CGSOCKCONT?
> 0
> -1
> AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,0
> 0
> -1
> AT+CIPMODE=0
> 0
> -1
> AT+NETOPEN
> 0
> -1
> ```

Si los envio por el monitor serie de **arduino IDE** no tengo el problema.

No entiendo cual es el problema.

¿Alguién tiene experiéncia en este tema?

Gracias.